# Custom error on field lost after updating the model

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form field to which I am trying to set custom errors manually using `.setErrors(..)`. It works.

I am using Angular 4.4.6

Now my use case is I need to clear the field and then set errors on it. My snippet looks like below:

Template:

```
 <form #myForm="ngForm">
   <app-somecomponent name="email" [(ngModel)]="email"></app-somecomponent>
 </form>
```

and in my component, I have this:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
   email: Email
    .....

   // some button in template calls this method passing the form reference
   setEmailEmpty(form: NgForm) {
       this.email = ''; // set email to empty.

       // show error below email field
       (<FormControl>form.controls['email']).setErrors({...})

   }
}
```

After setting the email to empty, I do not see the custom error.

But if I set email to empty using `(<FormControl>form.controls['email']).setValue('')` then I see the custom error.

What I am I doing wrong? what is the difference between using `setValue('')` and clearing the field directly.

**Note**: custom component implements ControlValueAccessor.

**Update:**

I noticed that waiting a tick before I set error works, like below

```
 this.email = ''; // set email to empty.

 // wait a tick and then show error below email field
 setTimeout(() => {
   (<FormControl>form.controls['email']).setErrors({...})
 }, 0)
```